# Handling dollars in Angular 2 Material Slider

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-material

I have a form in my Angular 2 Material application with, among other things, a price field modeled as a slider with a maximum, minimum, and step:

```
  <md-input type="range"
      [min]="minimumPrice"
      [max]="maximumPrice"
      [step]="priceTick"
      class="slider">
```

Prices are modeled in **cents** (i.e. with no fractions), but the front-end should display prices in **dollars**, e.g., a price of `12345` cents with a maximum of `50000` cents, a minimum of `0` cents, and a step of `5` cents looks like this now:

```
                12345
       0 |---------*---------------| 50000

              in steps of 5
```

but it should be displayed in terms of **dollars**:

```
                $123.45
   $0.00 |---------*---------------| $500.00

              in steps of $0.05
```

The form and slider work when displayed **cents**, but how can I get the slider to behave and display correctly with values in **dollars**?

The back-end price model is a `long` which is sent to the front-end as a `long` value (i.e., with no fractions) but I'm willing to change what I send to the front-end to simplify handling, if need be. So, the general question is: what's the simplest way to get `md-input` to display dollars correctly, and behave correctly?

Comment: How are you displaying the values currently?

Comment: Values are currently displayed in cents, @silentsod -- I'll update the question to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being entirely familiar with `Angular2 Material` I would venture using the [`CurrencyPipe`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html) combined with a template variable for the slider if you're eschewing model binding:

```
<md-input type="range" name="slider"
  [min]="minimumPrice"
  [max]="maximumPrice"
  [step]="priceTick"
  #slider
  class="slider" [placeholder]="slider.value | customCurrency">
    <span md-prefix>{{slider.min | customCurrency}}</span>
    <span md-suffix>{{slider.max | customCurrency}}</span>
</md-input>
```

The layout is probably incorrect but that is the gist of it, and you can muck around with this Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Fj3hDJmwRD4SvzlKu6R6?p=preview

Here's a very simple custom extension of the `CurrencyPipe` to remove the /100 and set formatting:

**custom-currency.pipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: "customCurrency"
})
export class CustomCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {}

    transform(value: any): string {
      return this.currencyPipe.transform(value / 100, 'USD', true);
    }
}
```

**module.ts**

```
import {CustomCurrencyPipe} from "[location]/custom-currency.pipe";
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({<...>, declarations: [<...>, CustomCurrencyPipe], providers: [<...>, CurrencyPipe]})
```

Comment: +1 This is **very** close to what I'd like, @silentsod -- thank you! Because I have this type of code in many places, I'd love to get the various `/100` tucked away in `.ts` files -- any way to do that when using the CurrencyPipe?

Comment: Maybe implement your own extension of `CurrencyPipe` and use it in place of the stock one. I'll put it in my answer.