# Apply pipe to display value of md-input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-material

I have a form in my Angular 2 Material application with a price:

```
  <md-input [(ngModel)]="price" placeholder="Price">
  </md-input>{{price|customCurrency}}
```

which [uses a custom version of the `CurrencyPipe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849714/handling-dollars-in-angular-2-material-slider/) as shown in this Plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OM039CYEsS5CfhEuZdBN?p=preview

But instead of showing the raw input field value:

```
  Price
  100              $1.00
```

I'd like to also apply the `customCurrency` pipe directly to the input field display value so it looks like this:

```
  Price
  $1.00
```

when I type 100. It'd be best if the pipe is applied to the display value as you type, but if it can only be done *on-blur* that would be adequate. Any ideas how this might possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a big difference in a pipe (effectively a simple function that transforms an input value into a string for display) and a custom input component that handles all the complexity with merging user input with a formatted value whilst not changing the cursor position, etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not (yet) possible in Angular 2; see [Angular 2 issue 13140](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13140). As a work-around, you can do:

```
  <md-input [(ngModel)]="Price" placeholder="Price: {{price|customCurrency">
  </md-input>
```

which looks a little bit nicer but not much:

```
  Price: $1.00
  100
```